# Just a simple guessing game

Tags: python, number-guessing-game

This is a simple guessing game I have made, an improvised one. I will do a GUI version of this shortly.

I'm looking for comments and interesting code ideas.

```
import random 

sec_no = random.randint(0, 10)

ncount = 0

att = 5

while True:
    sec_no = random.randint(0, 10)
    ncount = 0
    att = 4
    minp = input('''
                    1-start
                    2-help
                    3-quit
                 ''')

    if minp.lower() == 'start' or minp == '1':
        while ncount != 4:
            att -= 1

            try:
                uinp = int(input('Guess the no:'))
                if uinp == int(sec_no):
                    print('correct!!!!')   
                    break

                else:
                    print('incorrect!!!')
                    print(f'attempts left:{att}')

            except ValueError:
                print('invalid value!!!')
                print(f'attempts left:{att}')

            if ncount == 3:
                print('You lose!!')
                print(f'correct number is :{sec_no}')
                break

    ncount += 1

    elif minp.lower() == 'quit' or minp == '3':
        while True:
            print('are you sure you wanna quit?     [Y/N]')
            linp = input('>')

            if linp.lower() == 'y':
                print('Thanks for playing!!')
                exit()

            elif linp.lower() == 'n':
                break

            else:
                print("I don't understand that!!!")

    elif minp.lower() == 'help' or minp == '2':
        print('''You will be given 3 attempts,within these attempts you'll have to 
                 guess the right number from 0-10
                 good luck!!!''')

    else:
        print("I don't understand that!!")
```

Comment: The indentation here is off. Typo?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. I find it easier to create code blocks using lines just containing `~~~` before and after: you don't have to touch indentation. Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), improving the title of this post, too.

Answer (score 2):

There are few improvements you can do:

1. Remove the first `sec_no = random.randint(0, 10)`. You are already initializing it inside of the main while loop.
2. Create a variable that contains `minp.lower()`. Instead of calculating it over and over - keep it in a variable and avoid code duplication.
3. Get rid of `ncout` or `att`. They are practically saving the same thing, keep only `att` and change the while and if condition to `att > 0`.
4. Add some comments - File comments and function comments.
5. General python tip: do not write code in main, Use functions. Function for each case, function for main loop, [function to check if string is int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except) and the `__main__` should look like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_function()
```

Except for that - good logic, nice code :)

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a hint to the answer so you can broaden the range of numbers. This is just a quick example.

```
import random

num = random.randrange(1, 100)
lives = 5
print('''
Welcome to the guessing game. Guess a number between 1-100.\nYou have {} lives
'''.format(lives))
while True:
    try:
      if lives == 0:
        print('You died!\nThe number you were looking for is {}'.format(num))
        break
      guess = int(input('Guess: \n'))
      if guess == num:
        print('You win!')
        break
      if guess < num:
        lives -= 1
        print('Number is higher...\nlives: {}\n'.format(lives))
      if guess > num:
        lives -= 1
        print('Number is lower...\nlives: {}\n'.format(lives))
    except ValueError:
      print('Numbers only!')
```

The result:

```
Welcome to the guessing game. Guess a number between 1-100.You have 5 lives

Guess:
50
Number is lower...
lives: 4

Guess:
30
Number is lower...
lives: 3

Guess:
25
Number is lower...
lives: 2

Guess:
10
Number is higher...
lives: 1

Guess:
16
Number is lower...
lives: 0

You died!
The number you were looking for is 13
```

Comment: Really nice, I usually like to use [`fstrings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) instead of `format`. Just notice that this works for python3 and above.